# How to print the first value of an arraylist of doubles using printf

Tags: java

I know how to print the first value using println its just

```
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

But that doesn't work for printf. I need to know this for a computer science study guide. So therefore it has to be printf.

the printf code and error

System.out.printf(list.get(0));

method PrintStream.printf(String,Object...) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Double cannot be converted to String)
method PrintStream.printf(Locale,String,Object...) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Double cannot be converted to Locale)
1 error

Comment: show the `printf` code so we can see what is wrong with it.

Comment: System.out.printf(list.get(0));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple answer

```
     double dVal = 3.14;
     System.out.printf("%f", dVal);
```

See  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

and note format and printf, are equivalent to one another.

Comment: thank you this code worked  System.out.printf("%f", list.get(0));

Comment: This might not be obvious from the `printf` docs, but you can look at lots of documentation online for printf, it's a very well known function in C.  Java is not identical, but it is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your result like this

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);

    System.out.printf("%f", list.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.printf()` statements are for formatting Strings. One way you could go about doing this is by converting your double into a string using the `.toString()` method

`System.out.printf((list.get(0).toString()));`

Another way is by using format specifiers and conversion characters (ex. `%f`) to include your double values.

`System.out.printf("%.1f", list.get(0));`

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this :

```
    List<Double> myList = new ArrayList();
    myList.add(23.0);
    myList.add(3.0);
    System.out.printf(myList.get(0).toString());
```

Comment: *you need to convert it*  - my answer shows that you do not need to convert